# How to Combine 2D array in Python?

Tags: python

I want to combine array,
X of size (100,20) and
Y of size (100,10)
to an array Z of size (100,30)  Where X axis of both array is same!

Comment: Is zip() what you are looking for? If it's numpy array you can use np.concat()

Comment: What have you tried so far? How are your 2D arrays implemented, as that isn't a native datatype in python - is it a list of lists?

Comment: try list1.extend(list2)

Answer (score 1):

You can append lists to each other just with '+'

```
X = [[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]                                                          

Y = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]                                                             

Z = X + Y                                                                         

[[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```